# How to display all permissions a role has in laravel 5 entrust?

Tags: php, laravel-5

So, I want to show all permissions, which particular role has. I have written this peace of code:

```
    public function index()
    {
    $role = Role::first();
    $binding = $role->perms->toArray();
    dd($binding);
    //return view('binding.index', compact('binding'));
    }
```

So basically dd gives:

```
    array:1 [▼
      0 => array:7 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "name" => "create-news"
        "display_name" => "Create News"
        "description" => "/news/{news}/create"
        "created_at" => "2015-02-21 12:29:28"
        "updated_at" => "2015-02-21 12:30:21"
        "pivot" => array:2 [▶]
      ]
    ]
```

This is result for ::first() (one role). So, to sum things up, $binding is an array of roles, and each role is an array of permissions. How do I pass and extract data from such variable?
Example result required:
Role: User
Permissions: view-news;
Role: Admin
Permission: create-news, edit-news.

Or is it just 2 nested foreach loops?

Also, I have noticed that for Role::all(); I get error Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$perms. How so, I dont get this error for Role::first();?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load all roles (and also already eager load the permissions to save db queries):

```
$roles = Role::with('perms')->get();
```

Then just pass it to your view:

```
return view('binding.index', compact('roles'));
```

And loop over it there:

```
@foreach($roles as $role)
    @foreach($role->perms as $permission)
        {{ $permission->someproperty }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

---

Of course if you want it as an array you can also just call `$roles->toArray()`. The permissions will be nested inside the every role.

---

[More information about eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading)

Comment: Clean and works like a charm, exactly what I wanted. Didn't know of ::with('perms').

Comment: You're welcome! Make sure you read [this section in the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading) to learn more about eager loading

Answer (score 0):

Different ways to retrieve permissions assigned to a role in laravel 5.3

***Solution 1:***

```
Role::where('name', $roleParam)->first()->perms;
```

Note: Permission name can be any name exist into permissions table like below

$roleParam = 'add-user';

***Solution 2:***

```
$roleObj = Role::where('name', $roleParam)->first();

return $this->response->array($roleObj->perms);
```

This solution works with Dingo Router Helpers :-) Therefore you must use Helpers into base controller like mentioned below.

```
use Dingo\Api\Routing\Helpers;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests, Helpers;
}
```